# Upgrade WAS 8.5.5.12 to 8.5.5.23 in windows 11 local server

Tags: windows, websphere, websphere-8, windows-11, ibm-installation-manager

We are now working in java web projects deployed on IBM Websphere (WAS) 8.5.5.12. Our development environment as follows:

1. Developer PC OS : Windows 10/11
2. WAS Version: 8.5.5.12
3. IDE : Eclipse
4. WAS installed through installation manager
5. Repository in IBM Installation Manager : https://www.ibm.com/software/repositorymanager/com.ibm.websphere.DEVELOPERSILAN.v85

The WAS server will be upgraded to 8.5.5.23 later this year. We are now trying to figure out the procedures to upgrade 8.5.5.12 to 8.5.5.23 in our development PCs.

We've tried the following but can't upgrade to the target version.

1. In our local windows PC we upgraded IBM installation manager to latest 1.9.2.6
2. We try "Update" our current product (WAS 8.5.5.12). But the only option available is upgrade to 8.5.5.18
3. We try "Install" new package and looking for all versions /fixes available. It only allows me to 8.5.5.18 only.

Please help / share your experience in upgrading to 8.5.5.23 for local development purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The account your IBM ID is associated with does not have WebSphere entitlement, and in the 8.5 release only the 8.5.5.18 fix pack is available without entitlement.

The available fix packs are are limited if the account is un-entitled, and 8.5 is more limited than 9.0.

It's possible the ID you use to download via installation manager is just not associated with the "customer number" that has WAS licenses. That association happens at https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/supportaccess